# Are checksums unique?

Tags: checksum

Checksums, as we know, are a small amount of data that are computed from a larger set of data (usually to provide error detection). But how are they unique if there's less data? If they're not unique then multiple inputs would, by definition, produce the same checksum, and I would think that would defeat their whole purpose.

Comment: The general idea is that for a small number of bit errors the checksum is highly unlikely to match, e.g. a 16 bit checksum would have a probability of 1 in 64k of matching by chance. Normally a CRC is used rather than a simple checksum.

Comment: Checksums are not unique.